# log scale x with data at x=0

Tags: r, ggplot2

[As shown in this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1G57.png), is there a way to extend the left margin to display data points at x=0 when using log scale with the following codes so the data points at x=0 will be fully drawn instead of cut by about half as show on left side of plot?

```
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0095, 0.0095, 0.0095, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
y <- c(23975, 16852, 18924, 21086, 15940, 16308, 17443, 24729, 13513, 30260, 31883, 35960, 55485, 58366, 35607, 58119, 52414, 53990)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

p <-  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(min(data$x), max(data$x))), aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_point(data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))  +
      scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
p
```

Comment: `log(0)` returns `-Inf`, and ggplot treats `-Inf` as "the left edge of the plot". What you can do is add a small value to your 0s (or to all your data) to put them wherever you want relative to your other data.

Comment: As @Gregor said, you can fake it by shifting the points artificially - but doing so would rather misrepresent the data. Particularly if you then go on to draw a regression through the data. Zeroes and log scales do not play well together, so maybe think about another way to represent your data, or show the x=0 data separately form the others if you really need a log scale

Comment: Further to my last comment. I actually plotted your data and there are not many orders of magnitude to span, so a linear x scale works fine.  My advice - DON'T use a log scale

Answer (score -1):

A quick 'n' dirty, less-than-optimal workaround: turn off clipping and remove the y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0095, 0.0095, 0.0095, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.095, 0.095, 0.095, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
y <- c(23975, 16852, 18924, 21086, 15940, 16308, 17443, 24729, 13513, 30260, 31883, 35960, 55485, 58366, 35607, 58119, 52414, 53990)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

p <-  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(min(data$x), max(data$x))), aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_point(data, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y))  +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^(.x)))) + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank())

p <- ggplotGrob(p)
i <- which(p$layout$name == 'panel')
p$layout[i,'clip'] <- 'off'
grid.draw(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add the following to the `ggplot` and run

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.2, 0.5), expand = TRUE)
```

please fine tune `xlim` for better results.